# Events logs are not collected but event collection subscriptions are active

Tags: windows-event-log, winrm

A Windows Server 2008 R2 server is configured to collect Windows Event Logs, via a source initiated event subscription.

The subscription appears to be active but no events are collected.

[image: subscriptions section of windows event viewer showing active subscriptions]

On the client `Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin/Operational` has errors with event ID 105 like the following:

> The forwarder is having a problem communicating with subscription
>   manager at address
>   http://`<server name>`:5985/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC.
>   Error code is 2150859027 and Error Message is The
>   WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response
>   saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually
>   returned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management
>   protocol. .

and

> The forwarder is having a problem communicating with subscription
>   manager at address http://`<server name>`:5985/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC.  Error code is 1311 and
>   Error Message is WinRM cannot process
>   the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred
>   while using Kerberos authentication: We can't sign you in with
>   this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure
>   your device is connected to your organization's network and try
>   again. If you previously signed in on this device with another
>   credential, you can sign in with that credential.    Possible causes
>   are:   -The user name or password specified are invalid.   -Kerberos
>   is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified. 
>   -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.   -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port
>   does not exist.   -The client and remote computers are in different
>   domains and there is no trust between the two domains.  After checking
>   for the above issues, try the following:   -Check the Event Viewer for
>   events related to authentication.   -Change the authentication method;
>   add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration
>   setting or use HTTPS transport.  Note that computers in the
>   TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.    -For more information
>   about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help
>   config. .

and

> The forwarder is having a problem communicating with subscription
>   manager at address http://`<server name>`:5985/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC.  Error code is 2150858770
>   and Error Message is The client
>   cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify
>   that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
>   requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management
>   service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
>   destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
>   destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm
>   quickconfig". .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the collector is returning an incorrect hostname for the events to be sent.

This appeared to be caused by an `127.0.0.1` entry in the `hosts` file on the collector server for a hostname where the server was not accessible.

Resolution: add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to the beginning of the file.

Here you can see the the correct value being returned after the fix in `Microsoft-Windows-Windows Remote Management/Analytic`:

[image: Event log entry with relevant field highlighted]